# How can I call a JQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, this is like two question in one!

1. Why is this JQuery function call failing? or how should I call the JQuery function? Firebug tells me that `$('#login').slideup` is not a function.

   setTimeout("$('#login').slideup('slow');",2000);
2. How can I declare a JQuery function externally (not binding it to anything and not after `document().ready()` then later call it in my javascript functions?

For example:

```
function afterLogin(){
  $('#login').slideup('slow');
}
```

then later call it as:

```
setTimeout('afterLogin();',2000)
```

Help

Gath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the first part you can do

```
setTimeout(function(){$('#login').slideUp('slow');},2000);
```

the second part can be done exactly the same:

```
function afterLogin(){ $('#login').slideUp('slow'); }
```

then later call it as:

```
setTimeout(afterLogin,2000);
```

edit: fixed the casing from slideup to slideUp